# Bootstrap responsive table portion primefaces selectOneMenu not working

Tags: primefaces, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap with primfaces 6.1 in my application.In my page I am using bootstrap responsive table.In mobile view a plus icon appears in the first column.When I press the plus icon it will expand show remaining hidden columns.So now for me when I press plus icon p:selectonemenu has to be appeared but it is not.

```
    <table id="tableId" style="width: 100%;" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
    <tr><td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>
    <p:selectOneMenu  id="studentComboBox" style="width:100%"
    value="#{stud.name}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{stud.name}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

       <script type="text/javascript">
       //<![CDATA[
            jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {
                generateStudentTable();
            });
            function generateStudentTable()
            {                                       
                $('#tableId').DataTable({

                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "responsive": true,
                    "bLengthChange": true,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bSort": false,
                    "bInfo": true,
                    "searching": true,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "deferRender": true,
                    "pageLength": 10,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        null,
                        null,
                        null                        
                    ]
                });
            }
            //]]>
        </script>
```

Comment: Checked https://www.google.com/search?q=primefaces+bootstrap+problems+site%3Astackoverflow.com ? Bootstrap messes with css so it is sort of not very compatible

Comment: Please provide a fully testable example - only then can we help you. Using PrimeFaces together with Bootstrap works perfectly fine - we do it in many projects. But your example is incomplete. Please refer to [mcve].